# Azure data factory pipeline failure trigger execute only last pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I use azure data factory to configure my data pipeline.

The problem is failure trigger only works on the last pipeline. The intermediate one fails, but it does not trigger a failure alarm

All pipelines are connected by completion ( blue line )

[image]

Comment: I don't know whether the answer is the thing you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Thought

If you remove all the Failure lines. And then, let it "Copy data1" fail deliberately, if "Copy data2" works, it meanings

1. Completion line works.
2. Completion line and Failure line cannot happen at the same time.

Then, you can link "Copy data1" and "Copy data2" with a Failure line if you want  "Copy data2" to continue to work.

If you don't want "Copy data2" to continue to work, use the Success line.

#### Code/Result

Whether copy is right, copy2 will be triggered.

Copy1 is failed.

[image]

Copy1 is normal.

[image]

Comment: I wanted everything to be done, whether the copy activity failed or successful, so I connected it with a completion line (blue line).

But if I fail, I wanted to get an alarm, so I connected all the failure lines (red lines) to the web hook.

But it seems that the completion check is done earlier, so the failure is not triggered, so is there any way to execute both?

Comment: Now, when only execute webhook the last copy activity fails, the webhook does not execute even if the other copy activity fails.

Comment: Thank you. I'll test it and leave the result as a comment. I didn't see the photo attached and wrote the comment, but I'll check it. Thank you!!!

Comment: Your advice was not successful... I'm sorry, but I wrote a new posting. Can you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71703420/azure-data-factory-pipeline-failure-trigger-execute-only-last-pipeline-add-scre